# Можно ли при передачи из html формы данных массива в GET параметрах исключить преобразование квадратных скобок

Tags: php, html, form, get

Есть форма c 2-мя чекбоксами и кнопкой submit:

```
<form method="GET" action="result.php">
 <input type="checkbox" name="val[]" value="1" checked> var 1
 <input type="checkbox" name="val[]" value="2"> var 2
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

При нажатии кнопки submit идет переход на
result.php?val%5B%5D=1

т.е. квадратные скобки заменились на %5B и %5D.

Вопрос, а можно ли сделать так, чтобы в УРЛ вставлялись квадратные скобки без преобразования?

(вопрос чисто эстетический)

Comment: Т.е. чтобы в результате урл был result.php?val[]=1

Comment: Нельзя, RFC 3986 предписывает их обязательное экранирование

Comment: @andreymal не, ну на js потом можно всякие вещи делать типа `let url = window.location.toString();
url = url.replace('%5B', '[');
url = url.replace('%5D', ']');
window.history.pushState('', '', url);`

Comment: я все понял, спасибо больше за ответы!